# Is there a way to dynamically add buttons to a JSON table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table full of products from a JSON file. I would like to add a column which contains buttons for each product. Is there a way to do this?

JSON structure:

```
{
  "products" : [
    {
      "id" : "0",
      "name" : "Logitech G910 Orion Spectrum RGB Mechanical Gaming Keyboard - 
                UK-Layout",
      "price" : "119.99",
      "category" : "0",
      "description" : "Logitech 920-008017 G910 Orion Spectrum RGB Mechanical 
                       Gaming Keyboard - Black.",
```

HTML:

```
<table id =myTable class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
  <thead id = table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th id = "add">Add to Basket</th>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Code for table:

```
$.getJSON('products.json', function(data){
  var items = [];


  $.each(data.products, function(key, val){
    items.push("<tr data-category='"+val.category+"'>");
    items.push("<tr data-price='"+val.price+"'>");
    items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.id+"</td>");
    items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.name+"</td>");
    items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.price+"</td>");
    items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+val.description+"</td>");
    items.push("<td id=''"+key+"''>"+"<img src='"+val.images[0].src+"'width='150px'/></td>");


  });

  $("<tbody/>", {html:items.join("")}).appendTo("table");
});
```

Comment: Simply add the column?  I do not understand since you are adding columns why adding one more is a challenge here.  Can you elaborate on the issue perhaps?

Comment: So my products table contains 8 products. I'm not sure how to make jquery add a column with a button in each row. Is there a way to add buttons as the content is loaded into the table?

Comment: You add one with a img, just add one with a button element.

Comment: I tried this and couldn't get it to work

Comment: "<td><button>mybutton</button></td>" adds a button to a TD column

Comment: What did you try, and what happened that was not what you expected? And what do you want the button to do? We need this information so that we can give you a good answer.

Comment: Thank you, I have no idea why I couldn't do this I've been messing around with it for ages

Comment: @JackTaylor The button will be used to add the items to a basket

Comment: @Louys's answer will work. Can users alter any of the JSON data, by the way? If they can, then your code is vulnerable to [DOM-based XSS attacks](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/DOM-based_XSS). Even if users can't alter the data, it is good practice to escape your output anyway, so that you will not be vulnerable to XSS attacks in the future if you change how the data is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markup you provided is invalid. `tr` in the header is not closed, weird id's in it. I see no reason to append the `tbody` so put in in the markup.  Let's assume you have this table:

```
<table id='myTable' class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Add to Basket</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Now what you really want is to append a row for each product.  You have two `tr` in your array and neither are properly closed in that string array.  I simply created one row for each instead of two, I see no reason to have nested `tr` but you can revise if that is somehow desired but you would have to close those as needed properly.

You did not provide JSON for the image as your JSON was incomplete so I made a simple one to test and added a couple extra objects to test with.

Sample data:

```
var data = {
  "products": [{
    "id": "0",
    "name": "Logitech G910 Orion Spectrum RGB Mechanical Gaming Keyboard - UK-Layout",
    "price": "119.99",
    "category": "0",
    "description": "Logitech 920-008017 G910 Orion Spectrum RGB Mechanical Gaming Keyboard - Black.",
    "images": "first"
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "testa",
    "price": "119.99",
    "category": "2",
    "description": "testa desc.",
    "images": "afred"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "testb",
    "price": "119.99",
    "category": "2",
    "description": "testb desc.",
    "images": "bfred"
  }]
};
```

Code, a bit verbose to illustrate:

```
function getprod(data) {
  var items = [];
  $.each(data.products, function(key, val) {
    items.push("<tr data-category='" + val.category + "'");
    items.push(" id='" + key + "' data-price='" + val.price + "'>");
    items.push("<td class='row-id'>" + val.id + "</td>");
    items.push("<td class='row-name'>" + val.name + "</td>");
    items.push("<td class='row-price'>" + val.price + "</td>");
    items.push("<td class='row-description'>" + val.description + "</td>");
    items.push("<td><img alt='"+val.images+"' src='" +val.images+ "' width='150px'/></td>");
    items.push("<td><button type='button' class='cartbutton'>cart</button></td>");
    items.push("</tr>");
  });
  var tb = items.join("");
  console.log(tb);
  $("#myTable").find('tbody').append(tb);
}
$('#myTable').on('click', '.cartbutton', function() {
  var row = $(this).parents('tr');
  console.log(row.attr('id'), row.data('category'), row.data('price'));
});
// I used a function to work with the sample data, you can revise that below:
//$.getJSON('products.json',getprod);
getprod(data);// remove for real call
```

Comment: Thank you, this is my first time using javascript and I followed a tutorial online, obviously didn't help me that much. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, We all started at the beginning :)